# Empty TabContainer in Dojo Dialog

Tags: dojo, dialog, tabcontainer

The problem is that the TabConainer inside the Dialog is empty after opening although `selected="true"` is given (see the screenshot below). The content is called with dojo/html `html.set(node, contentHTML, {parseContent: true});`

When changing the tab by clicking on another one the content appears and the class "dijitVisible" is set for this div as it should be from the beginning. The attribute `nested="true"` is necessary since otherwise three select bars are shown over the tabContainer.

What can I do so that the content appears from the start on?

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" id="formDialog" data-dojo-id="formDialog" title="Edit member data">
    <div id="formContent" class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea" data-dojo-attach-point="formContent">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Empty content]

**Update:**

Here is the whole javascript for getting the content

```js
getForm = function(formID, urlAction){

    var contentHTML;
    var xhrArgs = {
        url: urlAction,
        handleAs: "text",
        load: function(data){
            contentHTML = data;
        },
        error: function(error){
            contentHTML = text_error_unexpected + ": " + error;
        },
        handle: function(error, ioargs){
            var node = dom.byId(formID);
            html.set(node, contentHTML, {parseContent: true});
        }
    }

    var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
};
```

**Update 2:**
This is the content that gets called and inserted in the above div "formContent" (I thought I make the description as simple as possible and lost some details on the way)

```html
<div id="form" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" data-dojo-attach-point="form" encType="multipart/form-data" action="#">
    <div style="width: 450px; height: 370px;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" nested="true">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Personal data" selected="true">
                Content 1
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Detailed data">
                Content 2
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Contact data">
                Content 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can show the code as to how do you get the value of **node** for  `html.set(node...` and where are you setting the content?

Comment: Your above code works fine. check this jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rxU83/ .May be the dojo code you wrote does something.. Can you elaborate more on the dojo code related to this?

Comment: @frank I added the complete script

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling either dialog.resize() or tabcontainer.layout() after adding it to the dialog?

Comment: I tried adding the dialog.resize() after the dialog.show() it does not work. But when I resize the browser it displays the contents of the first tab. Don't know how to get it working in the code. could not use tabcontainer.layout() as I am not able to get the handle to the tabcontainer widget. It gives me undefined.

Comment: The dialog.resize() does work, but it needs to be called after the widgets are initialized by the `html.set` call. So I added the dialog.resize() call with a time delay ( using setTimeout).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as to how the code below will place contents inside the first ContentPane (title="Personal data"). I am assuming that the parameter `formID = "form"`

```
html.set(node, contentHTML, {parseContent: true});
```

I can suggest an alterantive.
Use an **id** with the content pane as shown below.

```
<div id="content1" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Personal data" selected="true">
Content 1
</div>
```

Then use dijit/registry to get the contentpane widget in the **handle** function call as shown below.

```
handle: function(error, ioargs){
          var content= registry.bId(formId); // over here formId = "content1"
          content.set("content","<p>This is content for <b>Personal Data</b></p>");
          //content.set("content", contentHTML);

}
```

**EDIT 1**
This is may be one possible solution.
@Richard had suggested  dialog.resize(), which I did try to put it after the `html.set` code but it would not work.
What I have noticed is that the `html.set` takes some time to execute and the dialog.resize() does not work because it is
called before the completion of the `html.set` call.
`html.set` also complicates the issue as it does not provide any handle (promise object) to let us know when it has finished execution.
so the below solution uses a **setTimeout** call to delay the execution of the dialog.resize(). Hence would advice to put the value of delay time depending upon some actual UI testing.
Modified code.

```
handle: function(error, ioargs){
            var node = dom.byId(formID);
            html.set(node, contentHTML, {parseContent: true});
            var dialog = registry.bId("formDialog");
            setTimeout( function(){
                dialog.show();
                dialog.resize();
            },2000) // time delay of 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I get the error `TypeError: node is undefined` with that. I updated the description again maybe it helps.

Comment: if node is undefined, which obviously means that the form is not present in the DOM. Is the form with the given ID present? If yes, is the js code called after the Dom is ready?

Comment: It should be ready since I am calling require([..., "dojo/domReady!"], function(...) { before and I can see it in Firebug. Althought "formContent" is an empty Widget since it will be filled with the form itself via Ajax.